# The functionality of a driver circuit

Tags: driver, current-source, feedback, laser, functional-safety

I was requested to make a laser driver circuit for a course project. After some research, I found [this circuit.](https://odicforce.com/WebRoot/Store15/Shops/05c54fb6-7778-4d36-adc0-0098b2af7c4e/543B/B59A/ADD8/2F09/5C80/0A48/3538/B214/293227044713.png)

[image]

Can someone explain how this circuit works? What is 1R (R5&R6)? Can it be replaced with resistance?

I tried to simulate it in Proteous. The circuit works fine but there seems to be no current passing through the LM358 which is confusing.  Most branches are zero mA, but if I turn  RV1 up and down the current through the LED changes just fine. Here is a photo describing it. Ignore D4.

[image]

Comment: 1R simply means 1 Ω.

Comment: @ocrdu okay and what about this diode D1? Why is it connected after the GND? what does it do?

Comment: Reverse polarity protection?

Comment: @Mu'menYasser As for diode ``D1`` from the circuit it isn't clear why there are separates nodes for ``GND`` and ``0V``. Do you have a link which describes the circuit and provides more context?

Comment: @Mu'menYasser I notice the question has a ``functional-safety`` tag. Do you need to achieve certification to a specific functional safety standard?

Comment: @ChesterGillon I just need softstart safety and reverse current protection, but I'm little confused so excuse me if it is the wrong tag

Comment: @ChesterGillon here is the only link i could find for this circuit https://odicforce.com/epages/05c54fb6-7778-4d36-adc0-0098b2af7c4e.mobile/en_GB/?ObjectID=3231481

Comment: @Mu'menYasser The link contains ``Reverse polarity protection`` in the description, which explains the reason for ``D1``.

Answer (score 0):

It is a constant current linear driver for the blue LED D1.

You manually set the value of RV1 and the operational amplifier U1 automatically sets the value of the current that flows between the drain and the source of MOSFET Q1 and D1.

It's a linear amplifier circuit where RV1 sets the bias point of the MOSFET.

There's no AC or frequency dependent currents or voltages involved.

The capacitors you see work as filters of high frequency unwanted voltage spikes.

MOSFET Q1 might gets hot. Measure the value of the electrical power wasted in heat:

PQ1 = (V3 - V1) * IQ1   or   PQ1 = (V3 - V1) * ID1

Answer (score 0):

Working from the originally linked schematic:

[image]

[Most likely source.](https://odicforce.com/epages/05c54fb6-7778-4d36-adc0-0098b2af7c4e.sf/en_GB/?ObjectPath=/Shops/05c54fb6-7778-4d36-adc0-0098b2af7c4e/Products/OFL156)

- V+ and 0V

These are the power connections for the module.  V+ goes to 12V while 0V goes to the ground of the 12V power supply.

- Ground symbol

This is the internal ground of the module.  The circuit operates in reference to this signal. All internal measurements are made from ground.

- D1

Reverse polarity protection.  This prevents damage to the laser diode and the rest of the circuit in case someone connects the circuit to the power supply backwards.

- R1 and D2

1.2V reference voltage.  The circuit needs a stable reference voltage to use in maintaining the constant current output.  You need a steady reference point to aim at when trying to hold an output steady. D2 is a Zener diode with a Zener voltage of 1.2V.  It won't be precisely 1.2V in reality, but it should be fairly stable.

- R2 , RV1, C2

Target voltage for the current output.  R2 and RV1 are a [voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) to limit the voltage at C2 to less than about 0.555V.  Varying RV1 gives a voltage from 0V to 0.5555V at C2.  C2 is used to filter out noise caused by the wiper of RV1 scraping along the resistance track.

- R4, R5

These two 1 ohm resistors in parallel form a single resistor of 0.5 ohms.  This resistor is used to measure the current through the laser diode.  When current flows through a resistor, a voltage proportional to the current will appear across the resistor [(that's Ohm's law.)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)  E = IR  where E is volts, I is current in amperes and R is resistance in ohms.

- U1, Q1

Current regulation.  U1 measures the difference between the set voltage from RV1 (on U1 pin 3) and the measured voltage from the current sense resistor (U1 pin 2.)  The voltage at U1 pin 1 is adjusted so that Q1 conducts more or less current so that the voltage across the sense resistor matches the set voltage from RV1.

From Ohm's law, you can see that there will be approximately 0.5 volts across R4 and R5 when there is 1 A of current flowing through them.  Given that the adjustment range for RV1 is about 0.555V, you can get just a bit over 1 ampere of current through Q1 and the laser diode.

- C1

Local bypassing for the LM358.  This removes some noise on the power supply inputs as well as preventing noise from the LM358 from getting back out to the power supply.

- C3

Bypassing for the laser diode.  This prevents sudden changes in the current from flowing through the laser diode.  This includes such things as the surge when the circuit is turned on, but also any sudden changes that may occur due to varying RV1.  Such sudden changes may occur faster than the LM358 can regulate its output.  Without C3, the laser diode could be damaged by sudden, sharp changes in the output current.

When the circuit is operating, nearly no current flows through most of the circuit.  The LM358 uses only milliamperes to operate.  D2 will use a couple of milliamperes to form the reference voltage.  The output of U1 (pin 1) will only deliver current while changing the output voltage.  Once the regulator has reached the targeted output, there will be no current flow to the gate of the MOSFET.

Since this is part of your course work, I suggest you go through your class text book and see how the individual parts of the circuit line up with the things you should have learned in this course.  If the things I've described above aren't in your text book, then the circuit may be more advanced than your course expects.  Since you were given the assignment as part of the course, however, I expect you will find all of it described in the text book - though you may have to apply some thought to see how the text matches the circuit description.

Comment: thank you so much for this detailed answer, I just have a little problem regarding the Zener diode, 1.2V Zener Diodes is not available where I live, If can replace it with 3.3V zener diode, what adjustment should I apply? btw im trying to connect a laser diode of 3V and 2mA maximum current